# Bug in link rendering?

Tags: bug

It seems if URLs contain a `$`, this breaks markdown rendering. I'm guessing some interaction with the mathjax rendering. Example:

[open termination][2]

[$%201%201e-12%202.688763906446752%2050%205%2050%0A171%20176%20192%20496%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Aw%20128%20272%20176%20272%200%0Aw%20496%20192%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20496%20272%20544%20272%200%0Ar%20176%20192%20128%20192%200%20300%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ag%20128%20272%20128%20288%200%0AR%20128%20192%2096%20192%204%205%20150000000%205%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%204098%205%200.025%200%202%204%203%0A%0A%20%20[4]:%20https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%201e-12%202.688763906446752%2050%205%2050%0A171%20176%20192%20496%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Aw%20128%20272%20176%20272%200%0Aw%20496%20192%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20496%20272%20544%20272%200%0Ar%20176%20192%20128%20192%200%20300%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ag%20128%20272%20128%20288%200%0AR%20128%20192%2096%20192%204%205%20150000000%205%200%200%200.01%0Al%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%201.0000000000000001e-7%204.4651918219930954e-11%0Ao%204%2016%200%204098%205%200.025%200%202%204%203%0Ao%208%2016%200%204099%200.15625%200.000390625%201%202%208%203%0A" rel="nofollow noreferrer">short termination](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=<span class=)

[inductive termination][4]

[$%201%201e-12%202.688763906446752%2050%205%2050%0A171%20176%20192%20496%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Aw%20128%20272%20176%20272%200%0Aw%20496%20192%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20496%20272%20544%20272%200%0Ar%20176%20192%20128%20192%200%20300%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ag%20128%20272%20128%20288%200%0AR%20128%20192%2096%20192%204%205%20150000000%205%200%200%200.01%0A209%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%201e-12%202.656944995198298e-7%201%0Ao%204%2016%200%204098%205%200.025%200%202%204%203%0A%0A%20%20[6]:%20https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%201e-12%202.688763906446752%2050%205%2050%0A171%20176%20192%20304%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Aw%20128%20272%20176%20272%200%0Aw%20496%20192%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20496%20272%20544%20272%200%0Ar%20176%20192%20128%20192%200%20300%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ag%20128%20272%20128%20288%200%0AR%20128%20192%2096%20192%204%205%20150000000%205%200%200%200.01%0A171%20368%20192%20496%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Ar%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%20300%0Ar%20336%20192%20336%20272%200%20500%0Aw%20304%20192%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20336%20192%20368%20192%200%0Aw%20368%20272%20336%20272%200%0Aw%20336%20272%20304%20272%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%204098%205%200.025%200%202%204%203%0A" rel="nofollow noreferrer">capacitive termination](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=<span class=)

[conductance discontinuity][6]

[resistance discontinuity](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%201e-12%202.688763906446752%2050%205%2050%0A171%20176%20192%20304%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Aw%20128%20272%20176%20272%200%0Aw%20496%20192%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20496%20272%20544%20272%200%0Ar%20176%20192%20128%20192%200%20300%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ag%20128%20272%20128%20288%200%0AR%20128%20192%2096%20192%204%205%20150000000%205%200%200%200.01%0A171%20368%20192%20496%20192%200%202e-9%20300%2080%200%0Ar%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%20300%0Ar%20304%20192%20368%20192%200%20500%0Aw%20304%20272%20368%20272%200%0Ag%20304%20272%20304%20288%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%204098%205%200.025%200%202%204%203%0A)

URLencoding the `$` fixes the issue, though on a cursory search `$` doesn't seem to be something that's required to be urlencoded.

I did first create these links with ctrl-L and pasting the link, which did translate all the `+` into `%20`, so I guess that dialog already results in some re-encoding. An easy, if not entirely correct fix, would be to have that routine also urlencode any `$`.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps you can find the answer on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Mathjax).

Comment: Related question on Meta Stack Exchange: [A break is needed between two URLs if they include $ (if the site is mathjax enabled)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344164/295232)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the report and the workaround. I can't do anything about it simply as a moderator, but I encourage you to upvote [the report on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344164/a-break-is-needed-between-two-urls-if-they-include-if-the-site-is-mathjax-ena) for more visibility.

---

Technical note: The mentioned workaround of replacing `$` with `%24` will work in *most* cases but should not be relied on.

If you are an internet protocol enthusiast but don't want to bother looking it up yourself: The `$` character is in the "sub-delims" category in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (whose more familiar members are the `&`, `=`, and `+` of query parameters), which means that web servers are *allowed* to interpret `$` differently than `%24` if they choose to.

This is in contrast to the characters that *must* be treated differently when escaped, such as `/` and `%2f` (matters for relative URL resolution even if the server decides to serve `/foo%2fbar` with the same contents as `/foo/bar`), or required to treat the same (such as `A` and `%41`).